# Planet Colonization book with benevolent AI

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence, space-colonization, medieval

I am looking for the name of this series.

It starts with an intelligent ship and a crew of engineers that get a planet ready for colonization. After all of the engineers die the ship remains in space and watches the humans that were seeded on the planet. The humans on the planet know nothing of technology and come up with their own religions and customs similar to medieval times on Earth.

The book starts out as scifi but kind of descends into a fantasy series sprinkled with scifi.

Answer (score 5):

I'll have to re-read the first book but I think I finally found the series. I think this is the Safehold series by David Webber. I've been searching for this book series for days and finally found it moments after making this post.

Comment: That's a common thing, I think concentrating about it enough to create a post tends to sharpen faint memories and it comes back to you

Comment: I have actually read a lot of science fiction that starts out with a premise similar to what you described above. "These people are *descended from* colonists from Earth, but it's been many centuries and now they live in a medieval culture and don't really remember how their ancestors got here, and they don't know the difference between advanced technology and magic." So the Safehold books didn't pop into my head right away, because there were a great many other candidates!

Comment: in the safehold series they deliberately start a religion to suppress technology because they were hiding from aliens that could detect advance technology and had already wiped out the rest of humanity.  Then 'Merlin' comes along to overthrow the religion

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if you believe this is the book.